# Existing Java Project into Github

Tags: java, eclipse, github

I read around to see how to load an existing project into GitHub but I later got really confused. So in the end I did the following:

1. Created a project which uses the GitHub Repository I have (Library-Tracker) as the location.
2. Dragged existing Java files into src folder
3. Committed and pushed

The files showed up on github fine but is this the correct way to load projects onto Github?

**Edit: I used eclipse for all of the above**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ye, I think it's fine.

Another one is to create repo using

```
git init
```

and then

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git
```